# Loop images in PictureBox

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and I'm trying to make a basic application with Visual Studio.

One of the things I want to achieve is to download several weather maps from the Internet and make a loop with them (show one after the other after sorting them chronologically) so that you can see how the weather changes over time.

Downloading the images was quite simple, but now I can't decide what's the best approach (or at the least the most common) to show them one after the other.

- Should I have one single PictureBox and change it's image over time?
- Should I have several PictureBoxes one on top of each other and make them appear and dissapear over time?
- Any other approach you would recommend?

Also... when I tried changing the image with a loop to get the effect I'm looking for (sleeping the app after each change for a second), the app takes 10 seconds to start (the whole loop) and I can only see the last image in the PictureBox.

This obviously has to do with the app being busy and not refreshing the form.

After googling a bit I saw that I could add a BackgroundWorker... is that correct? Should I go down that path or am I missing something completely?

Would you be able to give me a few clues on how would you approach this application? I don't necessarily need to see the code.

As you can see I'm only beginning to code in Visual Studio and trying to learn by trial and error, so I'm just looking for a bit of guidance.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The simplest thing is to use a `timer` and for each `tick` change the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice Tutorial called [A Simple Image Slide Show](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23082/A-Simple-Image-Slide-Show)

This should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems quite easy!